# Interactive pre-generated views

Tags: .net, entity-framework, view

I'm using a WPF application that reads data by a WCF application hosted in IIS. 
To get data from the database I use Entity Framework 6.

My application is initial very slow therefore I wanted to use Interactive views. When I start my application the initial call is made and the views are created (a XML file). When I reset my application pool my program doesn't use the generated views in the XML but it creates again the XML file. 
With this code the XML is created:

```
using (var ctx = new DataReportingContext(request.ConnectInfo))
{                
    InteractiveViews
        .SetViewCacheFactory(
            ctx,
            new FileViewCacheFactory(@"d:\log\MyViews.xml"));
}
```

How can I re-use the views so I don't get the initial create of the views?

Comment: Any update on this?